# Find ranges in Matrix

Tags: r, matrix, vector

There is a vector of numbers like

```
c(3,10,24,29,37)->k
```

and a table

```
    c(1,3)->l1
    c(9,12)->l2
    c(24,27)->l3
rbind(l1,l2)->ll
rbind(ll,l3)->l3

   [,1] [,2]
l1    1    3
l2    9   12
l3   24   27
```

how can I find which of the numbers in the vector are in the range of the table. Here the result would be 3,24 and 10. Maybe just the indices of these numbers...

Comment: [How to make a great R reproducible example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Comment: It's not very clear, maybe `k[findInterval(k, sort(l3)) < length(l3)]`?

Comment: well everythign si reproducible...

Comment: You get a lot of warning when trying to create your data due incompatible lengths. It is also not clear why are you using a matrix structure rather just a vector

Comment: yes sorry - i just changed it ..

Comment: Maybe `sapply(k, function(x) x >= tbl[,1] & x <= tbl[,2])`

Comment: hi i get a matrix true false with dim 3,4 if I try that...that looks like it is not working...

Comment: I added the solution with the data

Answer (score 1):

You can try `sapply` with `any` and the conditional statements:

```
indx <- sapply(k, function(x) any(x >= l3[,1] & x <= l3[,2]))
k[indx]
[1]  3 10 24
```

Comment: is there any chance for a speed up? My table is like 60k lines and it takes really long (waiting over 15 minu now)