# Find values in matrix

Tags: r, matrix, any

The problem is the following

There is avector

```
k<-sample(1:100000,1000)
sort(k)->k
```

Then there is a matrix with ranges like

```
l<-c(1,100)
l1<-c(250,1000)
l3<-c(30000,60000)
l4<-c(80000,90000)
rbind(l,l1)->l
rbind(l3,l4)->ll
rbind(l,ll)->ll
ll->l3
```

Now I do have to find those numbers which are in the ranges of the table (like 1-100, or 30000 to 60000). Currently I use

```
indx <- sapply(k, function(x) any(x >= l3[,1] & x <= l3[,2]))
```

that is slow for a table (l3) with over 60k lines - is there any quicker way maybe?

Comment: You can use `cut` to get the grouping and then find the values in that group.

Comment: so i changed the 30k to 60k - if that is eadier to follow - sorry I dont understand how cut could help here

Comment: @heinwe Please don't repost. This is exactly the same question as [**your previous**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35012734/find-ranges-in-matrix), just with some new numbers. You should provide enough information in the (original) post so people trying to help you understands the size of your problem, not spending their time in vain.

Comment: well th orignal question is different in scope - right? it is unfair to assume that it hast o be larg scale while this is not!

Comment: Why your comment to @Pierre Lafortune then ("is there any chance for a speed up? My table is like 60k lines and it takes really long")?